Problem in activating conda env in github workflows
name: CI/CD Pipeline

on:
  push:
    branches:
       - main
       - HotelAvail_V2/noelsj007

jobs:
   deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - name: Checkout repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Install Miniconda
    run: |
      wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh
      bash miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda
      rm miniconda.sh
      export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
      echo 'export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH"' >> $HOME/.bashrc
  
  - name: Initialize Miniconda
    run: | 
      eval "$($HOME/miniconda3/bin/conda shell.bash hook)"
      conda init
      source $HOME/.bashrc

  - name: Activate Conda environment
    run: |
      eval "$($HOME/miniconda3/bin/conda shell.bash hook)"
      conda init
      conda activate accomenv

  - name: Install dependencies
    run: |
      sudo apt update

      pip install -r requirements.txt

  - name: Deploy to the servers
    run: |
      ssh <mtco-dev>@<192.168.1.69 > 'cd /idefix/idefix_django && git pull origin main && source $HOME/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate accomenv && systemctl restart your-service-name'
    env:
      SSH_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.SSH_PASSWORD }}

this is my pipeline workflow for github while running the workflow I got the following error, infact I have the conda env called accomenv already setup in this particular server, this is how I want to do this I need to create the conda env if it doesn't exist if it already exist I need to take the env how I can fix this.
0s
Run eval "$($HOME/miniconda3/bin/conda shell.bash hook)"
/home/runner/work/_temp/a90d10ee-abc9-4f95-a534-b4254c33937c.sh: line 1: 
/home/runner/miniconda3/bin/conda: No such file or directory
no change     /usr/share/miniconda/condabin/conda
no change     /usr/share/miniconda/bin/conda
no change     /usr/share/miniconda/bin/conda-env
no change     /usr/share/miniconda/bin/activate
no change     /usr/share/miniconda/bin/deactivate
no change     /usr/share/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     /usr/share/miniconda/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     /usr/share/miniconda/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     /usr/share/miniconda/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     /usr/share/miniconda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
no change     /usr/share/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
no change     /home/runner/.bashrc
No action taken.

